# Finding minimum height of binary tree with given inorder and level-order traversals

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, tree-traversal, inorder

The inorder and levelorder traversals for a binary tree along with the total number of nodes is given in a function definition, we have to calculate the minimum height of binary tree for the given inputs.

Can we calculate without constructing the tree?

```
func(int[] inorder, int[] levelorder, int n)
{
  // write code here
}
```

for example

- inorder traversal - `{ 4,2,5,1,6,3,7}`,
- levelorder traversal - `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`, `n=7`.

> And expected o/p was `3`

Answer (score 1):

Below code snippet would calculate the height of the tree without constructing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int minHeight(int inOrder[], int levelOrder[], int n)
{
    int i=1;
    queue<int>q1,q2;
    q1.push(levelOrder[0]);
    int k = 1,height = 0;
    while(!q1.empty() || !q2.empty()){
        if(!q1.empty()) height++;
        while(!q1.empty()){
            int val = q1.front();
            for(int i = 0;i<n;++i){
                if(inOrder[i] == val) break;
            }
            if(i>0 && inOrder[i-1] !=-1 && k<n)
                q2.push(levelOrder[k++]);
            if(i<n-1 && inOrder[i+1] !=-1 && k<n)
                q2.push(levelOrder[k++]);
            inOrder[i] = -1;
            q1.pop();
        }
        if(!q2.empty()) height++;
        while(!q2.empty()){
            int val = q2.front();
            for(int i = 0;i<n;++i){
                if(inOrder[i] == val) break;
            }
            if(i>0 && inOrder[i-1] !=-1 && k<n)
                q1.push(levelOrder[k++]);
            if(i<n-1 && inOrder[i+1] !=-1 && k<n)
                q1.push(levelOrder[k++]);
            inOrder[i] = -1;
            q2.pop();
        }
    }
 return height;
}

int main()
{
    int inOrder[] = {4,2,5,1,6,3,7}; //input1
    int levelOrder[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; //input2
    int n=sizeof(inOrder)/sizeof(int); ////input3
    cout<<minHeight(inOrder, levelOrder, n)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question : If the in-order and level order traversal of a tree are given, what is the minimum height of the tree**

Example 1 :

```
    input1 : {2,1,3}

    input2 : {1,2,3}

    input3 : 3

    Output : 2
```

Example 2 :

```
     input1 : {4,2,5,2,6,3,7}

     input2 : {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

     input3 : 7

     Output : 3
```

If you got this question in Campus round of Naggaro or on metti then it will a good solution for you

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def buildTree(level, ino):
    if ino:
        for i in range(0, len(level)):
            if level[i] in ino: 
                node = Node(level[i]) 
                io_index = ino.index(level[i])
                break
        if not ino:
            return node
        node.left = buildTree(level, ino[0:io_index])
        node.right = buildTree(level, ino[io_index + 1:len(ino)])
        return node
  
def height(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0 
    else:
        return max(height(root.left),height(root.right))+1

#This is the function you have to write
def minHeight(input1,input2,input3):
    global root
    root = buildTree(input1, input2)
    return height(root)


inorder = [4,2,5,1,6,3,7]
levelorder = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print("height : ",minHeight(levelorder,inorder,len(inorder)))
```

Answer (score 0):

a very simple approach is to build the tree and then find it's height.

let's suppose structure of the node is :
    struct Node
    {
        int key;
        struct Node* left, *right;
    };

```
Node* **newNode**(int key)
{
Node *node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
node->key = key;
node->left = node->right = NULL;
return (node);
}
int **getHeight**(Node* root){
    if(root==NULL) return 0;
    return max(getHeight(root->left)+1,getHeight(root->right)+1);
}
Node* **getNode**(Node* root,int key){
    if(root!=NULL){
        if(root->key == key) return root;
        return getNode(root->left,key) != NULL ? getNode(root->left,key):
        getNode(root->right,key);
    }
}
void **buildTree**(int inorder[], int levelOrder[], int i, int j,int n)
{
  Node* head = newNode(levelOrder[0]);
  i++;
 int comp = 0;
 while(i<j){
      int key = levelOrder[comp];
      Node* ptr = getNode(head,key);
      int k = n-1;
      while(k>=0 && inorder[k]!=key) k--;
      if(k>0 && inorder[k-1]!=-1){
          ptr->left = newNode(levelOrder[i]);
          i++;
      }
      if(k<n-1 && inorder[k+1]!=-1){
          ptr->right = newNode(levelOrder[i]);
          i++;
      }
   inorder[k] = -1;
   comp++;
}
int height = getHeight(head);
  **cout<<height<<" ";**
}
```

Comment: The code involves constructing the tree with the help of both arrays and then calculating min height, which I had done in the test. I was wondering to calculate height without tree construction :/

Comment: yeah, you can do even without constructing the tree.i have pasted that code too.thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
yes, you can do that without even constructing the tree.
for that use two queue.
see given below code for better understanding.

void **buildTree**(int inorder[], int levelOrder[], int i, int j,int n)
{
    queue<int>q1,q2;
    q1.push(levelOrder[0]);
    int k = 1,height = 0;
    while(!q1.empty() || !q2.empty()){
        if(!q1.empty()) height++;
        while(!q1.empty()){
            int val = q1.front();
            for(int i = 0;i<n;++i){
                if(inorder[i] == val) break;
            }
            if(i>0 && inorder[i-1] !=-1 && k<n)
                q2.push(levelOrder[k++]);
            if(i<n-1 && inorder[i+1] !=-1 && k<n) 
                q2.push(levelOrder[k++]);
            inorder[i] = -1;
            q1.pop();
        }
        if(!q2.empty()) height++;
        while(!q2.empty()){
            int val = q2.front();
            for(int i = 0;i<n;++i){
                if(inorder[i] == val) break;
            }
            if(i>0 && inorder[i-1] !=-1 && k<n)  
                q1.push(levelOrder[k++]);
            if(i<n-1 && inorder[i+1] !=-1 && k<n) 
                q1.push(levelOrder[k++]);
            inorder[i] = -1;
            q2.pop();
        }
    }
 cout<<height<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum possible height of a binary tree is `log2(n+1)`, where n is the number of nodes.